# How do I find linux kernel version from a virtual machine snapshot or memory image?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine

I was loading up a virtual machine and then suspended it. I got .vmem (virtual memory image) and the .vmss (snapshot) file. To analyze both files using volatility, I need to create a profile based on the kernel version of the memory image. On the normal vm, it is running a limited shell which does not allow me to use the normal commands to find the linux version. I remember finding something that worked but I skipped over it. I ran the command on my own linux pc and specified the memory image.

It went along the lines: of command (something(name) and then you specify the memory image and then you put grep Linux

this told me the version of the memory image but I skipped over it because I thought it was incorrect. Now, I can no longer find that command.

Comment: Does this article help you? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-print-linux-unix-kernel-version/

Comment: No, I do not have normal bash shell in the vm. I have the memory image and the snapshot image and need to find the linux version using those files

Comment: Check if the [`binwalk`](https://manpages.debian.org/binwalk/binwalk.1) tool can find anything interesting in the image, even if not made for this case.